# What is wrong with this pub sub code in javascript using the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have this pub sub code

```
export const subscribe = (eventName, callback) => {
  pubsub.addEventListener(eventName, (e, data) => {
    callback(e.detail);
  });
};
export const unsubscribe = (eventName, callback) => {
  pubsub.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
};

export const publish = (eventName, data) => {
  pubsub.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: data }));
};
```

But unsubscribe doesn't appear to work and I don't know why.

```
const setTargetFn = () => {
  unsubscribe("setTargetUnitId", setTargetFn);
  createMessage("Great job! Now attack it by pressing 1 and going near it", 0);
};

subscribe("setTargetUnitId", setTargetFn);
```

The subscribed event keeps getting called even after I call unsubscribe... Please help

Comment: What is `pubsub`?

Comment: Do you need to subscribe before unsubscribe? I don't know pub sub npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
unsubscribe("setTargetUnitId", setTargetFn);
```

It is not `setTargetFn` that has to be unregistered. The actual function to be unregistered is ...

```
(e, data) => { callback(e.detail); }
```

... since that is what you pass to `pubsub.addEventListener`.

Your code will work fine if you register the `callback` directly:

```
var subscribe = (eventName, callback) => {
  pubsub.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
};
```

Demo:

```js
const subscribe = (eventName, callback) => {
  pubsub.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
};

const unsubscribe = (eventName, callback) => {
  pubsub.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
};

const publish = (eventName, data) => {
  pubsub.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: data }));
};

const setTargetFn = ({ detail }) => { 
  unsubscribe("setTargetUnitId", setTargetFn);
  console.log("Great job! Now attack it by pressing 1 and going near it");
  console.log("Event detail", detail);
};

subscribe("setTargetUnitId", setTargetFn);
```

```html
<div id="pubsub"></div>

<button onclick="publish('setTargetUnitId', { foo: 'bar' });">publish setTargetUnitId</button>
```

Comment: OH That makes so much sense! Thank you